# Redis mass insert is not working in windows

Tags: windows, command-line, redis

Am trying to use mass insert feature of redis using a simple command as below. This is the one i have in text file input.
`"*3\r\n$3\r\nSET\r\n$3\r\nkeys\r\n$5\r\nvalues\r\n"`
And then i run below command but the values are not inserted in redis,
`echo "$(.\lua_poc\mass_insert.txt in.redis)" | .\redis-cli.exe --pipe`

The output says `Replies:0` always.

```
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Last reply received from server.
errors: 0, replies: 0
```

We use redis 4.0.9 version in windows 10. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo is doing something strange. The below command worked out for me.
cat .\lua_poc\mass_insert.txt | .\redis-cli.exe --pipe